# Chamar o método de uma superclasse específica

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Suponha que eu tenha a seguinte estrutura hierárquica em Java:

Primeiro uma classe `Avo`:

```
public class Avo {
    protected String nome;

    public void falar() {
        //Codigo aqui
    }
}
```

Em seguida tenho uma classe `Pai` que herda de `Avo` e sobrescreve seu método falar:

```
public class Pai extends Avo {
    @Override
    public void falar() {
        //Codigo aqui
    }
}
```

Por fim tenho uma classe `Filho` que herda de `Pai` e mais uma vez sobrescreve o método falar:

```
public class Filho extends Pai{
    @Override
    public void falar() {
        //Chamar método falar da classe Avo

       //Resto da implementação
    }
}
```

Existe alguma forma de no método falar da classe `Filho` chamar o método falar da superclasse Avo em vez do método da superclasse `Pai`? Sei que em C++ dá pra fazer `Avo::falar()`, tem algo parecido em Java?

Comment: [Jon Skeet diz que isso é uma péssima ideia em se fazer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586397/5524514)

Comment: Isso viola a encapsulação e não é permitido no Java. Você até pode fazer uma gambiarra (não faça!), mas a depender do que você queira, pode ser que haja outros caminhos mais simples.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não pode, se você herdou de `Pai` tem que se conformar com esta classe. Nem é problema de `Filho` quem `Pai` herda. Se está precisando fazer isso, a modelagem provavelmente está errada.

Pra mim C++ deixa quebrar o encapsulamento. Acho que o mecanismo sequer foi criado para isto e sim para acessar classes na horizontal, já que permite herança múltipla, não na vertical.

Talvez o que você quer é apenas uma interface, eventualmente com método implementado nela. A maioria das heranças que eu vejo aqui no site não deveria ser uma herança completa, estabelecer contratos, ou simples reuso não exige e na maioria das vezes não pode ser através de herança.

Não posso dizer a forma correta porque não sei qual é o problema, a pergunta apenas fala em acessar o método da avó e isto não dá. Cada problema tem uma solução diferente com o mecanismo adequado.

Comment: `Se está precisando fazer isto, a modelagem provavelmente está errada.` - essa foi a primeira frase que me veio à cabeça após ler a pergunta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou corrigir minha modelagem.

Answer (score 1):

Se quem fez a classe `Pai` (talvez você mesmo) decidiu substituir o método da classe `Avo` por um outro, é porque ele era inadequado, incompleto ou coisa assim.

Se por outro lado, a classe `Filho` quer reutilizar o método de `Avo`, então a classe `Pai` simplesmente não deveria tê-lo substituído.

É simples assim, você substitui aquilo que você quer apagar e jogar fora da superclasse. Se você substituiu, mas não queria apagar e nem jogar fora, é porque não deveria ter substituído para começo de conversa.

Há várias formas de se lidar com este problema e chegar-se em uma modelagem diferente para resolvê-lo. Entretanto, o seu exemplo é artificial demais para que eu possa sugerir um contorno que se aplique ao seu caso real.

Comment: Sim, concordo que o erro está no meu modelo. Obrigado